# Initializing array with results of variadic class template type's member function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

Say I have a template type ...

```
template<typename ...Ts>
struct SomeStruct {
    
    std::tuple<Ts...> some_tuple;

}
```

... where I'm sure any type expanded from `Ts` all share a base class, and thus some member function that returns some type `R`.

How could I go about collecting the results of calling that member function on each type in `Ts`, for example in something like `std::array< R, sizeof...(Ts) >`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that all `Ts...` element are supporting a `foo()` method, returning a `R` value, I suppose you can use `std::apply()`, if you can use C++17

```
std::apply([](auto ... vals)
           { return std::array<R, sizeof...(vals)>{ vals.foo()... }; },
           some_tuple);
```

or maybe simply

```
std::apply([](auto ... vals)
           { return std::array { vals.foo()... }; },
           some_tuple);
```

using `std::array` deduction guides.

If you can use only C++14, you can emulate `std::apply()` using `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence`